# generate two files with different extensions with the same unique id

Tags: php

I believe it's a matter of logic but I can't solve it.
I have a code that converts any video file to mp4, but at the moment I'm only converting to .gif. I wanted to know how I can generate a .mp4 and a .gif file with the same unique id.

I tried something like this

```
$finalFilePath = $targetDir . uniqid() . ".gif" ".mp4";
```

However, I was not successful.
It is only one file generator
In this case a uniqueid.gif file that is actually mp4.
and the intention is to generate both with the same unique id.

Thank you very much in advance.
Any help is welcome.

update more content to ask --->
Hello, using this code below I can generate the 2 files, but the problem is, two files are generated but both should have the same uniqid. however they are generated with different names, I'm having difficulties in creating a variable that stores only one uniqid this is my big problem.

```
 if(move_uploaded_file($videoData["tmp_name"], $tempFilePath)) {
            
            $finalFilePath = $targetDir . uniqid() . ".gif" ;
            $finalFilePath2 = $targetDir . uniqid() . ".mp4";


            if(!$this->insertVideoData($videoUploadData, $finalFilePath)) {
                echo "Insert query failed\n";
                return false;
            }
            
             if(!$this->convertVideoToMp4($tempFilePath, $finalFilePath2)) {
                echo "Upload failed\n";
                return false;
            }
```

Function Upload.

```
public function upload($videoUploadData) {

        $targetDir = "uploads/videos/";
        $videoData = $videoUploadData->videoDataArray;

        $tempFilePath = $targetDir . uniqid() . basename($videoData["name"]);
        $tempFilePath = str_replace(" ", "_", $tempFilePath);

        $isValidData = $this->processData($videoData, $tempFilePath);

        if(!$isValidData) {
            return false;
        }

        if(move_uploaded_file($videoData["tmp_name"], $tempFilePath)) {
            $finalFilePath = $targetDir . uniqid() . ".gif";

            if(!$this->insertVideoData($videoUploadData, $finalFilePath)) {
                echo "Insert query failed\n";
                return false;
            }


            return true;

        }
    }
```

---

Function ConvertVideoToMp4

```
public function convertVideoToMp4($tempFilePath, $finalFilePath) {
        $cmd = "$this->ffmpegPath -i $tempFilePath -pix_fmt rgb24 -r 4 -vf scale=540:-1 $finalFilePath 2>&1";

        $outputLog = array();
        exec($cmd, $outputLog, $returnCode);
        
        if($returnCode != 0) {
            //Command failed
            foreach($outputLog as $line) {
                echo $line . "<br>";
            }
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

---

Comment: So, what's the problem? Calling `uniqid` twice will generate different IDs, but nobody keeps you from calling it once and store the result in a variable to be used twice

Comment: Hello thanks for your reply, yes my big problem is to create a variable that stores the same uniqid and forward it to $finalFilePath and $finalFilePath2. That's exactly what you said, but I have no idea how to create a variable to use in both outputs of the uploaded file.

Comment: Why is creating such a variable a problem? What have you tried to do this? What exactly is not working with that? Just remember: don't call `uniqid` twice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `uniqid` once and store it to a variable and use it how many times you want.
I think the better way to create a unique id is:

```
$bytes = random_bytes(16);
echo bin2hex($bytes);
```

`random_bytes()` generates cryptographically secure pseudo-random bytes. Further, passing its output to another function `bin2hex()`, will give you unique random string.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. What makes you think that this is a "better way"?

Answer (score 1):

```
$id = uniqid();
$finalFilePath = $targetDir . $id . ".gif" ;
$finalFilePath2 = $targetDir . $id . ".mp4";
```

Simple ;)